# Is there any way to allow to push only specified local branch to specified remote?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-remote

### description

Here are 2 remotes, `origin` and `foobar`.

- origin has two branches, `master` and `xxxxx`
- foobar has only one branch `master`

origin is my main remote and I have local branches same as origin,
so there are `master` and `xxxxx`.

Sometimes I need to push xxxxx to foobar/master (not foobar/xxxxx),
by putting a command `git push foobar xxxxx:master`.

But I'm afraid to push master to foobar/master by mistake.

### So the issue is

Is there any way to prevent the master to push foobar?
Or, is there any way to allow only xxxxx to push to foobar?

Branches which belong to origin are possiblly to be incleased, and I don't want to push any other branches to foobar but only xxxxx is needed to be pushed as master to foobar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you need to set up explicit push mapping in the configuration:

```
git config remote.foobar.push refs/heads/xxxxx:refs/heads/master
```

and then use git push foobar without explicit branch specification.

Additionally you may set up [pre-push](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook which would validate commits being pushed.

Comment: It looks nice way! :D For safe I tried to prepare pre-push hook to prohibit strictly, it wasn't difficult and worked well. But for just avoiding mistake, the config looks enough. thanks!

Comment: ah, only one thing.
`git config remote foobar refs/heads/xxxxx:refs/heads/master` didn't success. so I changed this command to
`git config remote.foobar.push refs/heads/xxxxx:refs/heads/master`.
my git version is 2.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `git push` will sync local branch with that remote branch which local branch is tracking.

if you checkout local branch by `git checkout --track -b foobar_master foobar/master`, when you run `git push`, foobar_master branch will be synchronized with foobar/master.

Please google "remote-tracking branch" for more details.

By the way, you can run `git branch -vv` to confirm which remote branch your local branch is tracking.

Comment: I don't need to track `foobar/master`. The branch which I need to push to `foobar/master` is `xxxxx` and this branch tracks `origin/xxxxx`. But I didn't know -vv option, it will help me. thank you for your information.